# Setting up an encrypted connection for secure socket funneling

Tags: ssl, ssh, openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

[Secure Socket Funneling (SSF)](https://securesocketfunneling.github.io/ssf/) can be used as an alternative to SSH.

The suite uses certificates to secure its connections.

If you use the default configuration, anyone who also has the default configuration can connect to your SSF server. That's probably not what you want.

There is a description which files are necessary to change this at:

https://securesocketfunneling.github.io/ssf/#how-to-configure

[image: ssf required cert files]

A tutorial how to generate those can be found at their github repo:

https://github.com/securesocketfunneling/ssf#how-to-generate-certificates-for-tls-connections

There are 3 steps outlined:

1. [Generating Diffie-Hellman parameters](https://github.com/securesocketfunneling/ssf#generating-diffie-hellman-parameters)
2. [Generating a self-signed Certification Authority (CA)](https://github.com/securesocketfunneling/ssf#generating-a-self-signed-certification-authority-ca)
3. [Generating a private key and a certificate (signed with the CA)](https://github.com/securesocketfunneling/ssf#generating-a-private-key-and-a-certificate-signed-with-the-ca)

In detail:

**Generating Diffie-Hellman parameters**

```
openssl dhparam 4096 -outform PEM -out dh4096.pem
```

**Generating a self-signed Certification Authority (CA)**

The content:

```
[ v3_req_p ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
```

should be given into `extfile.txt` and

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout ca.key -out ca.crt -days 3650
```

**Generating a private key and a certificate (signed with the CA)**

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout private.key -out certificate.csr
openssl x509 -extfile extfile.txt -extensions v3_req_p -req -sha1 -days 3650 -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -in certificate.csr -out certificate.pem
```

These steps create the following, mapped to the required files above:

1. `./certs/dh4096.pem`
2. `./certs/trusted/ca.crt`
3. `./certs/private.key` and `certificate.pem`

To create my customized certs I used

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
```

**Step 1** I had to change to this to work properly:

```
openssl dhparam -outform PEM -out dh4096.pem 4096
```

For **Step 2** I created `extfile.txt` like described and ran:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout ca.key -out ca.crt -days 3650 -subj '/CN=www.mydom.com/O=My Company Name LTD./C=US'
```

as well as

For **Step 3**:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout private.key -out certificate.csr -subj '/CN=www.mydom.com/O=My Company Name LTD./C=US'
```

and

```
openssl x509 -extfile extfile.txt -extensions v3_req_p -req -sha1 -days 3650 -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -in certificate.csr -out certificate.pem
```

At the end the mismatch is: You need a file `./certs/certificate.crt`, but you have `certificate.pem`

I tried to transfer is using:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in certificate.pem  -out certificate.crt
```

But then I get the following error with those created files:

[image: error cert]

What is the correct way here to create `certificate.crt` ?

---

(I don't know if this is the right space from Stack Overflow for this question. If it is not, please feel free to correct).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

You just have to change `certificate.pem` to `certificate.crt` in the last step.

So the whole process is:

Put

```
[ v3_req_p ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
```

into `extfile.txt` and run

```
openssl dhparam -outform PEM -out dh4096.pem 4096
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout ca.key -out ca.crt -days 3650 -subj '/CN=www.mydom.com/O=My Company Name LTD./C=US'
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout private.key -out certificate.csr -subj '/CN=www.mydom.com/O=My Company Name LTD./C=US'
openssl x509 -extfile extfile.txt -extensions v3_req_p -req -sha1 -days 3650 -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -in certificate.csr -out certificate.crt
```

From the created files move

`dh4096.pem`, `private.key` and `certificate.crt` in the `certs` folder

and

`ca.crt` in `certs/trusted`.

If you do this for client and server you can start the server and the client can connect.